# Video broadcasting from server based on Django to all clients

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django, webrtc

I'm building a website based on Python/Django as a backend and react.js as a frontend. The situation is: Django gets a list of videos from a database. this list should be broadcast to all clients (it is like a TV stream).
By searching, I found that webRTC can handle video streams by doing peer-to-peer. what I understand is that webRTC makes a client connect to a client but in my situation, I need the server to broadcast videos to all clients.
Now, Is webRTC is the best solution in my case? if so, how many clients can be served at the same time?

Comment: m.kholy   Do you find any solutions to this?  i have the same problem as you...

Comment: unfortunatly, I  didn't find any solution.